# Haskell function definition error: Not in scope

Tags: haskell, option-type

I'm new to Haskell, and I'm stuck with an example. I'd like to experiment with the Maybe type, but my code does not compile:

```
divide100By :: Int a -> Maybe a
divide100By x = case (Int x) of 
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just x -> 100 / x

main = putStrLn ("Result: " ++ show (divide100By 5))
```

But I'm always getting the error:

```
Not in scope: data constructor 'Int'
```

I'm afraid I don't quite get the function definition in Haskell (the divide100By :: Int a -> Maybe a part)... Can someone please tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: `Int` does not take a type argument, so you want `divide100By :: Int -> Maybe Int`. Your function body also has at least 3 other problems...

Answer (score 4):

The integer type is `Int`, writing `Int a` means nothing since `Int` does not take arguments.

Also, `Int x` is not an expression, so you can't `case` on that.

Further, you use `case` with `Nothing/Just x` when you have a `Maybe a` type and you want to check what is its value. Here instead you want to construct a `Maybe a` type.

Try this instead:

```
divide100By :: Int -> Maybe Int
divide100By 0 = Nothing
divide100By x = Just (100 `div` x)
```

or

```
divide100By :: Int -> Maybe Int
divide100By y = case y of
   0 -> Nothing
   x -> Just (100 `div` x)
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work, I have seen this solution somewhere before. But can you also tell me why 'case' will not work?

Comment: @ZachJ `case` does work (see the edit), but you can only `case` on the input, which is an integer and not a `Maybe Int`, so you can't pattern match against `Nothing/Just x`.